# How exactly to use Cayley's Hamilton's theorem to find $A^{50}$ in this case? (matrix recursion equation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ I'm supposed to find $A^{50}$ using the Cayley Hamilton theorem.

My Attempt:

$|A-\lambda I| = 0 \implies \lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0$

So $A^2-2A+I = O \implies A^{50}=2A^{49} - A^{48}$

But using this method, I'll need to know $A^{49}$ and $A^{48}$ to find $A^{50}$. But that doesn't seem the right way. This seems like some sort of matrix recursion but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Have you computed a few small powers of $A$? There's a very simple pattern.

Comment: The minimal polynomial is $x^2-2x+1$. Compute the remainder of the division of $x^{50}$ by $x^2-2x+1$. The value of $A^{50}$ is equal to evaluating that remainder. Observe that the remainder is linear. Therefore, **no powers of $A$ need to be computed**. Observe also that while you could compute the remainder by doing long division, it is actually easier in this case to compute it by indeterminate coefficients, since $x^2-2x+1$ and its derivative vanish at $x=1$.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle I couldn't understand the reasoning behind what you're trying to do. What does the remainder of $x^{50}$ divided by $x^2-2x+1$ give me? Why should I compute it? Could you please elaborate

Comment: $x^{50}=(x^2-2x+1)Q(x)+R(x)$. Therefore $A^{50}=(A^2-2A+I)P(A)+R(A)=R(A)$, where the last equality follows because $A^2-2A+I=0$ by Cayley-Hamilton. The good thing is that the remainder $R$ will have degree strictly smaller than $2$.

Comment: Ah, right. BTW how did you calculate the remainder so quickly? Is there any trick? If I do long division it's becoming very lengthy @SphericalTriangle

Comment: Use indeterminate coefficients. $x^{50}=(x-1)^2P(x)+A(x-1)+B$. Putting $x=1$ gives $1^{50}=B$. Passing $B$ to the LHS, dividing by $x-1$ and evaluating again at $x=1$ we get $x^{49}+x^{48}+...+x+1=\frac{x^{50}-1}{x-1}=(x-1)P(x)+A$. Therefore $50=A$.

Comment: Ah. I see that I was typing up this solution at the same time as you were typing it in the comments. I didn't realise that the approach had already been mentioned.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle This is great. Thank you very much! If you don't mind, put this as an answer and I'll select it as the best answer. :)

Comment: I think it is best if you write it spot perfect and select it. That way you make sure you understood and as an extra get those points from this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by the division algorithm we have that
$$
  x^{50} = (x^2 - 2x + 1) P(x) + ax + b
$$
for some constants $a$ and $b$, and some polynomial $P(x)$.

Letting $x = 1$ gives us that $a + b = 1$. We thus have that
$$
  x^{49} + x^{48} + \dots + x + 1 = \frac{x^{50} - 1}{x - 1} = (x - 1) P(x) + a,
$$ 
and substituting $x = 1$ into this relation gives us that $a = 50$, which in turn implies that $b = -49$.

We thus have that
$$
  x^{50} = (x^2 - 2x + 1) P(x) + 50x - 49,
$$
and so we have that
$$
  A^{50} = (A^2 - 2A + I) P(A) + 50A - 49I = 50A - 49I =
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 50 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

***Hint***

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=I_2+B$$
First matrix is identity matrice,the second one is nilpotent $B^2=0$

Answer (score 3):

You can compute $A^2,A^4,A^8,A^{16},A^{32}$ quite easily (repeated squaring).

Then compute $A^{50}=A^2A^{16}A^{32}$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are several ways to proceed. One thing you could do is try to write down $A^2, A^3, A^4, \dots$ in terms of $A$ and $I$, spot a pattern, and use induction:

- $A^2 = 2A - I$
- $A^3 = 2A^2 - A = 2(2A - I) - A = 3A - 2I$
- $A^4 = 2A^3 - A^2 = 2(3A - 2I) - (2A - I) = 4A - 3I$

$\vdots$

Alternatively, you could repeatedly square:

- $A^2 = 2A - I$
- $A^4 = (A^2)^2 = (2A - I)^2 = 4A^2 - 4A + I = 4(2A - I) - 4A + I = 4A - 3I$
- $A^8 = (A^4)^2 = (4A-3I)^2 = \dots$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A$ is already in its Jordan form. Thus, for any differentiable function $f$ we have

$$f(A) = \begin{bmatrix} f(1) & f'(1) \\ 0 & f(1)\end{bmatrix}$$

In particular for $f(x) = x^{50}$ we have

$$A^{50} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 50 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)^2$, hence by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem $A^{n+2} = 2 A^{n+1}-A^{n}$ holds for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. With respect to the entries of $A^n$ this implies that $\{A^n_{11}\}_{n\geq 0},\{A^n_{12}\}_{n\geq 0},\{A^n_{21}\}_{n\geq 0},\{A^n_{22}\}_{n\geq 0}$ are sequences of values of linear polynomials. Since
$$A^0=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\quad A^1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad A^2=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
by interpolation we get $A^{n}_{11}=A^{n}_{22}=1$, $A^n_{21}=0$ and $A^n_{12}=n$ for any $n\geq 0$.